# Run Powershell script on TFS server for publish to Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, tfs, build-definition

I try to configure TFS for Continuous Delivery to Azure [by this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-continuous-delivery/)
In article TFS published package to Azure with Powershell script.
When build starts I get errors like `ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzureDeployment:String) [], CommandNotFoundException`. Looks like I didn't install Azure cmdlets, but I install all from Web Platform Installer.
And when I try to run script locally on server - it works and deploys package.

In article Powershell starts by adding `InvokeProcess` to template with `Filename="PowerShell"`.

I think I just don't run Powreshell correctly. 
Maybe somebody has some ideas which command should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a solution

Powershell cann't find Azure module.
Add this before Import-Module Azure command in script

```
$env:PSModulePath=$env:PSModulePath+";"+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell"
```

Comment: A different path works for me -

$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";" + "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement"

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you installed the cmdlets on the user profile. Try re-install after logging in with the account running the build service.

Comment: No, now I have only one account on server, for experiment, and tfs uses it credentials :(